# How to use PHP's strtotime

Tags: php, date, time, strtotime

I'm new to PHP and kind of struggling with the basics, please excuse the horrible code to come.

What I'm trying to do is parse a date retrieved from an XML file, and see if that date falls on a Monday/Tuesday/etc.

I can't seem to get it right, any help is much appreciated.

```
<?php

    foreach ($xml as $x)
    {
        $time = strtotime($x->Start);
        echo $time;

       if(date('D', $time) === 'Mon') 
           echo "Booking for Monday";
       else if(date('D', $time) === 'Tue') 
           echo "Booking for Tuesday";
       else if(date('D', $time) === 'Wed')
          echo "Booking for Wednesday"; 
       else if(date('D', $time) === 'Thu')
          echo "Booking for Thursday"; 
       else if(date('D', $time) === 'Fri')
          echo "Booking for Friday";
   }

?>
```

$time isn't outputting anything, and the only result coming back is "Booking for Thursday" for each XML record (x5) despite only two of the records falling on a Thursday.

If I output the results by:

```
echo $x->Start;
```

That works fine and outputs "15/07/2013 9:30:00 a.m.".

Cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately that string representing your date isn't in the list of recognized PHP date/time string formats http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php

Comment: I think you're going to need to manipulate it a bit. I'll try and come up with something to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date looks like `European format d-m-y` and uses `American format m/d/y` seperator.

> Note:
>
> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed.

Instead of

```
$time = strtotime($x->Start);
```

Try

```
$time = strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$x->Start));
```

Additional Info :[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 1):

you have to convert your time string($x->Start) to one of the [**Supported Formats**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) before passing it to the strtotime.

Replacing / with . would change your date to a support format. but double check to be sure.

```
$time = strtotime(str_replace('/', '.',$x->Start));
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you already have an accepted answer, but I would strongly recommend that you take a look at [PHP's DateTime classes](http://php.net/datetime). They are extremely useful and can make seemingly complex date operations trivial.

In your particular case, I would replace:-

```
$time = strtotime($x->Start);
```

with:-

```
$time = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s a', $x->Start);
```

You can then format the date as you wish using the [`\DateTime::format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method.